# Add months but the parameter is from the data JCL

Tags: mainframe, dfsort

I have data like this

```
----+----1----+----2----+----3----+-- 
000000002320110328087YY01200000020124
```

I want to `add the months` from `column 11-18, with the value from 24-26`

I am thinking about the outrec field is like this

```
11,8,Y4T,ADDMONS,24,3,TOGREG=Y4T(-)
```

But when I try it , it give rc=0016, because of the operand error ,

I am thinking about store the value of 24,3 to a variable then i put it to variable , but i dont know if JCL can provide that .. anyone can help?

Notes : i use dfsort , not icetool

and i dont want to hardcode it because i already try 11,8,Y4T,ADDMONS,+12,TOGREG=Y4T(-), and it works but if can , iwant to replace the "+12" with the  value from column 24-26

Answer (score 4):

The syntax diagram for `ADDMONS` for your case is shown as:

```
p,m,Y4T,ADDMONS,p,m,f,TOGREG=Y4T(-)
```

You're missing the `f` subparameter. Since the number of months to add is a series of digits, the format would be `UFF`. I ran this sort job:

```
//SORT#010 EXEC     PGM=ICEMAN                                     
//SYSOUT   DD       SYSOUT=*                                       
//SYSPRINT DD       SYSOUT=*                                       
//SORTIN   DD       *                                              
000000002320110328087YY01200000020124                              
/*                                                                 
//SORTOUT  DD       SYSOUT=*                                       
//SYSIN    DD       *                                              
           SORT     FIELDS=COPY                                    
           OUTREC FIELDS=(11,8,Y4T,ADDMONS,24,3,UFF,TOGREG=Y4T(-)) 
/*
```

The result in SORTOUT is:

```
2012-03-28
```

Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to do this with plain DFSORT.

For instance PARSE would not work, because it would fail to resolve `%2`:

```
INREC PARSE=(%1=(ABSPOS=11,FIXLEN=8),
             %2=(ABSPOS=24,FIXLEN=3)),
      BUILD=(%1,Y4T,ADDMONS,+%2,TOGREG=Y4T(-))
```

You might want to look at [sort exits](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.1.0?topic=guide-using-your-own-user-exit-routines) if you'd like to go with DFSORT.

Answer (score 0):

You get a bad return code because DFSORT doesn't know how to interpret the three bytes you gave it with 24,3.

You should use : `11,8,Y4T,ADDMONS,24,3,ZD,TOGREG=Y4T(-)`

The ZD that I have inserted means : Zoned Decimal. It corresponds to a `PIC 9 USAGE DISPLAY` in Cobol.

You can interpret COMP-3 with PD and COMP-5 or BINARY with BI.

Comment: No, he doesn't get an ABEND; the sort step ended with return code 16, and that is **not** the same as an ABEND. And it is **not** the JCL, but the sort program which reports the syntax error.

Comment: I'm sorry, on my mainframe it is reported as an abend U0016, it might just be an overhead we have at work, hence my erroneous remark :) I will correct my answer thanks to your insightful comments.

Comment: Well, if I think about it, some installations have steps running a program that does nothing but abending with U0016. This program is run depending on the return code of previous step(s). The job scheduler will then recognize the job has failed. Also, DFSORT can be setup to ABEND instead of returning with return code 16 in case of errors. Sorry for not having thought of these possibilites.